# Issue with useState in React component with Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

## Issue with useState in React component with Storybook

I just set up Storybook on a new project, and I have a very basic stateful component, like so:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import './foo.scss';

interface IProps {
  text?: string;
};

export default function Foo(props: IProps) {
  const {text} = props;
  const [bar, setBar] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="foo">
      <div className="foo__text">{ text }</div>
      <button
        className="foo__button"
        type="button" 
        onClick={ () => setBar(bar + 1) }>
          { bar }
      </button>
    </div>
  )
};

Foo.defaultProps = {
  text: 'hello world',
};
```

And I have a bare-bones story for, as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";

import Foo from "./Foo";

const meta: Meta<typeof Foo> = {
  title: 'Foo',
  component: Foo,
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof Foo>;

export const DefaultStory: Story = {
  args: {
    text: 'I am text',
  },
};
```

When I run Storybook (which builds without error) and try to view the story, I am greeted by this:

> TypeError
> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
> Call Stack
> useState
>       vendors-node_modules_react_index_js.iframe.bundle.js:1632:21
> Foo
>   components-Foo-Foo-stories.iframe.bundle.js:158:72
> ...

Note that this works fine if I remove the usage of `useState`, and there are no errors in the Storybook command line. This seems very simple, but I am totally baffled - what am I doing wrong?

Some details:

- React 18.2.0
- Typescript 5.1.3
- Storybook 7.0.20 *(same versions for storybook-react, storybook-cli, and storybook-essentials)*

Comment: This error only happens after build? Or in dev happens too? Could you please provide your build script?

Comment: @NoNam4 The component works in the web app itself without issue; there is only an issue in the storybook UI. 
By build script, do you mean ./storybook/main.js?